# How come tt[9] is '4' after strcpy has changed its value?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char tt[20] = "9081726354";
    strcpy(tt, tt + 3);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(tt) - tt[9] + '5');

    return 0; 
}
```

After `strcpy`, `tt` is now `1726354` and its length is `7`. ASCII of `'5'` is `53`. But I don't get how `tt[9]` is `'4'` after string pointed by `tt` is changed.

Comment: From the man page for `strcpy`: The source and destination strings should not overlap, as the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, guys! That was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the specification from the C17 Standard:

> **7.24.2.3 The `strcpy` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <string.h>
>     char *strcpy(char * restrict s1,
>                  const char * restrict s2);
> ```
>
> The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` (including the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `strcpy` function returns the value of `s1`.

Copying the string at `tt + 3`, which comprises 8 bytes, to `tt` will indeed cause copying between overlapping objects and thus has **undefined behavior**.

Yet since the destination is in front of the source, it is probable that the copy will take place as expected and the first 8 bytes of `tt` will be overwritten with `"1726354"` and a null byte. The byte at offset `9` is not changed and still has the value `'4'` so your `printf` statement may produce `7 - '4' + '5'`, that is `8`, but the C Standard does not guarantee this behavior.

In fact you have another instance of undefined behavior as you are passing a value of type `size_t` for a conversion specifier `%d`. `size_t` has a different size from `int` on 64-bit systems, hence the type mismatch has undefined behavior too. You can detect this kind of mistake by increasing the compiler warning level: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror`.

Here is a corrected version that reliably outputs `8`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char tt[20] = "9081726354";
    memmove(tt, tt + 3, strlen(tt + 3) + 1);
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(tt) - tt[9] + '5');
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `size_t` values can be passed to `printf` with a conversion specifier `%zu` or `%zd` but many legacy systems do not support this C99 extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        int main(void) {
            char tt[20] = "9081726354";
            printf("Before: %s\n",tt);
            strcpy(tt, tt + 3);
            printf("After: %s\n",tt);
            printf("Length: %d,\ntt[9]: %d,\n'5': %d\n",strlen(tt),tt[9],'5');
            printf("Result: %d\n", strlen(tt) - tt[9] + '5');
            printf("Start analysis:\n");
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                printf("%d: %c\n",i,tt[i]);
            return 0; 
        }
```

Perhaps it's junk value taken. Its the same set of last characters that gets repeated:
check with different string

```
 #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        int main(void) {
            char tt[20] = "9081726399";
            printf("Before: %s\n",tt);
            strcpy(tt, tt + 3);
            printf("After: %s\n",tt);
            printf("Length: %d,\ntt[9]: %d,\n'5': %d\n",strlen(tt),tt[9],'5');
            printf("Result: %d\n", strlen(tt) - tt[9] + '5');
            printf("Start analysis:\n");
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                printf("%d: %c\n",i,tt[i]);
            return 0; 
        }
```

printf cannot tell where the string ends and continues to print garbage values.

Answer (score 0):

IT is an UB in the general.

```
char *safestrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    memmove(dest, src, strlen(src) + 1);
}
```

But in this copy direction all sane implementations work OK.

So the explanation is very easy.

[image]

As you see the bytes after the new terminator have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes as 8 in gcc.

Before `strcpy(tt, tt + 3);`, the length of array `tt` that is returned by `strlen` is 10 even though you created a array of size 20. This is because when you initialize the array with the numeric string  `char tt[20] = "9081726354";` the compiler adds a null terminating character at the end of string and `strlen` will return length of 10.

During `strcpy(tt, tt + 3);` you essentially copies the numeric string from `tt + 3` i.e. value `1` to the null terminating character at the start of your string. Now your `tt[7] = '\0'`, hence `strlen` after `strcpy` gives you a length of 7.  Kindly note you have not overwritten tt[9] hence it still holds the value `'4'`.

Finally, `strlen(tt) - tt[9] + '5'` is essentially is `7 - '4' + '5'`, which is `7 -52 + 53 = 8`.